# Enable "Standard" security level for a *single* website in Tor

Tags: javascript, email

Many of you are certainly aware that Proton mail is broken when using any security level but "Standard" in Tor, that is, the lowest security level available. Whitelisting Proton in NoScript is not enough, because Tor blocks all JavaScript in both "Safer" and "Safest" security levels.

I appreciate the strictness of the "Safest" security level, and do not want to disable it completely. Rather, I would like to allow JavaScript only on Proton, and no other website. How to achieve this?

### Edit:

I'm using Proton's ".onion" domain, and not the clear web version.

Comment: Do you use their Onion Service at https://protonmailrmez3lotccipshtkleegetolb73fuirgj7r4o4vfu7ozyd.onion/ or the clearnet presence?

Answer (score 1):

Use a separate browser for that, like Firefox. When you're launching Tor Browser - an instance of Tor is launched as well and you do have a proxy that listens to requests on your localhost - so just find this proxy and point the extra browser there. Tor browser is a way twisted app, and it has it's uses - and adding an exception like you're talking about would break much more things in it than will resolve. So it's OK for any piece of s..oftware just not to have all the features imaginable, including Tor Browser. Just use another one for a single particular exception you need.

Comment: Very nice solution. Yes, I might create a new Firefox user profile with no extensions, to try and reduce tracking to a maximum, and have it access that Tor proxy you mention. That's actually a very nice idea, as it doesn't require to downgrade the security in the entirety of my Tor browser. +1. Will mark this as the solution once I figure it out on my system! Thank you again, I appreciate your time.

Comment: @GPWR Actually, the Tor Browser itself is a over-mangled Firefox ESR, and it tweaked that deep? so you can't lower the security mechanisms as you asked: it's hardcoded and not manageable by user. It has it's uses and bonuses, but also brings some BDSM as well. So don't try to hammer a nail with a microscope - the tool is not for that, just use a proper tool! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I use Tor Browser with "Safer" settings. With that I went to https://account.protonmailrmez3lotccipshtkleegetolb73fuirgj7r4o4vfu7ozyd.onion/signup and it showed me the following page:

[image: signup page for Proton.me]

I was able to add an email address and password. The next windows asked for confirmation that I really want to use the free plan and I had to fill in a CAPTCHA.

After all those steps my mailbox was created and it showed me the mailbox. So far I can use Proton with my "Safer" settings in Tor Browser without any issues.

[image: Mailbox view of Proton]

Proton wrote in 2022 that they want to create a [new experience with Tor](https://proton.me/blog/updated-tor-site). They work closely with the Tor Project to make sure that Tor users can use their site. For this purpose they created [a special site with information for Tor users](https://proton.me/tor). The main thing is that one should use the Onion Service. By using this Onion Service Proton should work with Tor Browser.

Comment: +1. Thank you for your detailed and complete answer, I appreciate it. In my Tor browser, which is also the latest version, using Proton won't work unless I have the lowest security level. Do you know why this difference occurs? Is it because we have different builds, and could that make such a difference? I *am* using the Tor domain, yes. Thanks for pointing that out, I'll edit it into my question. God bless.

Comment: When playing around with Proton for the first time, it worked when I clicked to [register for a paid account](https://account.proton.me/signup?plan=bundle2022&billing=12&ref=prctbl&minimumCycle=12&currency=EUR&product=mail&language=en). After that I could also use Proton with the free one. I don't know if this helps, but might be worth a try.